# Develop for iOS not buying a Mac

Tags: android, ios

I started in Android sometime ago, but as I don't have a Mac I can't practice Swift and, obviously, develop too. I desconsider using hackintosh or similar. My point is: I should buy a Mac now and develop for both platforms simultaneously, or wait for the money I'll get in Android to buy a Mac?

Comment: We use only English here.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm sorry man. I'll try to translate and post again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run OS X in a Virtual Machine on a Windows platform. You'll be able to get XCode on your VM which is running on your windows, this will also save you ALOT of money.

Other than that you can still develop iOS apps and test them with frameworks like  [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)  but you will need OSX to generate a certificate to publish your application. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll invest in a better PC, so I can run games too haha. I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but can I publish my app using the VM?

Comment: Yes you can, it's like having a real mac.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks!

Comment: No problem @LéoSantos, enjoy your PC!